# Check if textbox of other process is the active control

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, pinvoke

I want to check if other process textbox control is the active control in the other process main window by the textbox handle.

The code should look like:

```vb
Dim TheMainWinDowHandle As IntPtr = Process.GetProcessesByName("proccessName")(0).MainWindowHandle
If TheMainWinDowHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
    Dim TextBoxHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(TheMainWinDowHandle, 0, "Edit", "TextBox Inner Text")
    If TextBoxHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
        Dim TheActiveHandleInTheMainWindow As IntPtr = GetActiveHandleFrom(TheMainWinDowHandle) 'TheActiveHandleInTheMainWindow = The Focused Control Handle Of "TheMainWinDow".
        If TheActiveHandleInTheMainWindow = TextBoxHandle Then
            MsgBox("The TextBox Is onFocus")
        Else
            MsgBox("The TextBox Is Not In Focus.")
        End If
    End If
End If
```

How can I do it (c# / vb.net)?

Comment: Please post your finds as an answer, you will be able to accept it after couple days I think.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer:

    Use the `GetForegroundWindow` function to get the window with which the user is currently working.
    Use the `GetWindowThreadProcessId` function to get the ID of both this window and yours.
    Use the `AttachThreadInput` function to temporarily associate your thread's message queue with the thread owning the other window.
    Use the `GetFocus` function to get the hWnd!
    Use the `AttachThreadInput` function again to disconnect from the other thread.
Source:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34752/Control-in-Focus-in-Other-Processes